# How can I get the number of count each item in association rules in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to get the number of count for each item that includes rules like that,
A==>B,C,D
B==>A,C
C==>B

In these rules,
I want to get like that `A=2`, `B=3`, `D=1`, `C=3`.

```java
public class MDSRRC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file =new File("C:\\sar.txt"); 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 
        Set<String> leftSide = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> rightSide = new HashSet<String>();

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line=sc.nextLine();
            String[] lineSplited = line.split("==>");
            String[] leftStrings = lineSplited[0].split(",");
            for (String string : leftStrings) {
                leftSide.add(string);
            }

            String[] rightStrings = lineSplited[1].split(" ");
            for (String string : rightStrings){
                if (string.length() > 0 && string.charAt(0) == '#'){
                     break;
                 }
                 rightSide.add(string);
            }
            //System.out.println(rightSide);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the problem?

Comment: why do you look for '#'? why do you split by " "? why isn't the code formatted with proper indentation so humans can read and help you?

Comment: can you also explian more the "rules" , interpretation can be slightly different from person to person

Comment: It is unclear to me what those rules mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Rules mean association rules in datamining in which contains frequent itemset. For example,{Milk==>Bread} by this rule, a customer buy Milk in a supermarket and also buy Bread together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are counting each character no matter if it is on the left or right side, you can use just one result structure. Datatype Set is nice if you just want to know the different kind of characters that occures but you also want the count so I suggest to change your result data type to a Map so you can keep a counter for every character.

So replace leftSide and rightSide by a single Map instance and for every character you encounter, check if it exists already in your Map. If so, add one to the value part of that entry, if not put the new character to the map with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    File file = new File("D:\\sar.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap();

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] lineSplited = line.split("==>");
        String first = lineSplited[0];
        resultMap.putIfAbsent(first, 0);
        resultMap.put(first, resultMap.get(first) + 1);
        String[] right = lineSplited[1].split(",");
        for (String a : right) {
            resultMap.putIfAbsent(a, 0);
            resultMap.put(a, resultMap.get(a) + 1);
        }
    }
```